# Why does my browser (firefox) in Ubuntu 14.04 keep randomly dimming?

Tags: firefox, screen, battery

To be more clear:

Sometimes when I browse on firefox or chromioum, the screen dims to a grey screen and 
freezes for a couple of seconds to a minute, and then the full color comes back, but with some lagging of the mouse pointer for a second.

Am I doing too many things at once on the browser or is there possibly something malicious going on in the background?

I already know it is not the battery, because it does it even while it is charged fully.

I've only been working with (k)ubuntu for a short period of time, (2 yrs) and I wanted to get other opinions.

Thanks in advance

-running on a nuked previous win8 os with ubuntu 14.04 on a 64 bit toshiba satellite c55-b5202 w/ an intel 2.16 ghz dual processor-

Comment: It means that Firefox is not responding. Like when a program freezes on Windows the title bar says "(not responding)"; on Ubuntu the window turns gray. How much RAM does your computer have?

Comment: Ah, I figured, but i had hoped it wasn't the case (4 gigs)